# Using perl to add 48 hours to a specific date

Tags: perl, datetime

I have a date in the format YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss and I want to add 48 hours to this date.  For instance I have the date 2018-02-05 12:00:00 and I want to add 48 hours to this date to get the date 48 hours from 2018-02-05 12:00:00 in the same format YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss?

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: You will have to _parse_ the string with a module that supports _date math_, then _add the interval_ and _convert the date back to a string in the same format_. You should be able to find solutions for all of those steps with a little help of Google or the Stack Overflow search. :)

Comment: what timezone do you want to add the hours in?

Comment: Do you want to add 48 hours or 2 days? Not every day has 24 hours in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds;

my $str = '2018-02-05 12:00:00';
my $format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S';
my $tp = localtime->strptime($str, $format);
$tp += ONE_HOUR * 48;

print $tp->strftime($format);
```

Comment: No, my comment was accurate. Your original code added 2 days. I have fixed your answer so that it adds 48 hours.

Answer (score 4):

To add 48 hours using DateTime,

```
# In America/New_York,
# 2018-02-05 12:00:00 ⇒ 2018-02-07 12:00:00
# 2018-11-03 12:00:00 ⇒ 2018-11-05 11:00:00
$dt->add( hours => 48 );
```

To add 2 days using DateTime,

```
# In America/New_York,
# 2018-02-05 12:00:00 ⇒ 2018-02-07 12:00:00
# 2018-11-03 12:00:00 ⇒ 2018-11-05 12:00:00
$dt->add( days => 2 );
```

---

How to parse and format:

```
use DateTime::Format::Strptime qw( );

my $format = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
   pattern   => '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
   time_zone => 'local',
   on_error  => 'croak',
);

my $dt = $format->parse_datetime('2018-02-05 12:00:00');
$dt->set_formatter($format);  # Automatically format correctly on stringification.

...

say $dt;
```

Answer (score -1):

To add 48 hours using Time::Piece,

```
# In America/New_York,
# 2018-02-05 12:00:00 ⇒ 2018-02-07 12:00:00
# 2018-11-03 12:00:00 ⇒ 2018-11-05 11:00:00

my $tp = localtime->strptime($timestamp, $format);
$tp += ONE_HOUR * 48;  # Or:  $tp += ONE_DAY * 2;
say $tp->strftime($format);
```

To add 2 days using Time::Piece,

```
# In America/New_York,
# 2018-02-05 12:00:00 ⇒ 2018-02-07 12:00:00
# 2018-11-03 12:00:00 ⇒ 2018-11-05 12:00:00

my $tp = Time::Piece->strptime($timestamp, $format);  # Pretend the dt is UTC even if local!
$tp += ONE_DAY * 2;  # Or:  $tp += ONE_HOUR * 48;
say $tp->strftime($format);
```

**Important**

There is no difference between `ONE_DAY * 2` and `ONE_HOUR * 48`.

```
$ perl -MTime::Seconds -e'CORE::say( ONE_DAY * 2 )'
172800

$ perl -MTime::Seconds -e'CORE::say( ONE_HOUR * 48 )'
172800
```

Yet, 2 days is not the same thing as 48 hours. That's why we have to pretend the date-time is a UTC date-time (even when it's not) when adding days. Dealing with mixed amounts (such as 1 day and 1 hour) is impossible.

Personally, I avoid this very error-prone module.

---

Common bits:

```
use feature qw( say );

use Time::Piece   qw( localtime );
use Time::Seconds qw( ONE_DAY ONE_HOUR );

my $format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S';

...
```